# Divide world map into panels of specific countries/regions

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2

I have the following points:

```
> dd
           area         Lon       Lat
1    2530000.00  -84.744000  39.57500
2    5300000.00   -3.200000  54.66000
3     100000.00   -2.970000  54.40000
4      10632.91  -89.494500  46.23046
5     190000.00   -2.923600  54.50630
6     239000.00   -3.260200  54.42850
7     930000.00   -3.264400  54.53120
8     223045.80   12.303000  55.93400
9    3236000.00   -3.691800  52.94930
10     94000.00   -3.028400  56.49910
11   4700000.00   -3.075300  54.33810
12    400000.00   -3.819200  52.99930
13    258924.72  -89.473300  46.21046
14    340000.00  -89.612000  46.00200
15      5524.00  -89.606000  46.00800
16     57000.00   -3.962000  52.79470
17    170000.00   -3.025900  54.42720
18   3000000.00   -3.381200  54.52220
19  23674200.00   18.587000  59.84600
20   1000000.00   -2.990000  54.36000
21    140000.00   -3.990100  57.54240
22    110000.00    9.452022  56.01752
23    640000.00   -3.019500  54.44840
24    100285.00   12.303000  55.98500
25    664549.00    9.391000  56.02000
26   1513724.00  -79.135600  45.37960
27      7862.06  -89.505900  46.24369
28  60900000.00   10.070000  45.72400
29 163268000.00   35.588000  32.81700
30      2468.00  -89.678000  45.99500
31     51000.00  -85.349000  42.41100
32     51000.00   -4.041800  53.01420
33   1057000.00   -4.546000  56.21300
34     93000.00   -5.429600  57.49210
35   1114000.00   -4.281000  55.00210
36     99000.00   -3.321500  56.95920
37    111000.00   -4.509200  56.22730
38  71000000.00   -4.616000  56.10500
39    600000.00   -3.350000  54.58000
40  38282400.00  -89.424000  43.10500
41     58818.50  -89.521300  46.25745
42     37833.00  -89.722000  45.99800
43      4624.00  -89.705000  46.00500
44    970000.00   -4.131900  53.12800
45      3000.00          NA        NA
46     10000.00   -2.990800  54.37210
47    127000.00   -4.430400  55.09330
48  79855500.00  176.267000 -38.08200
49  34600000.00  176.419000 -38.03700
50    500000.00   -2.386400  53.35400
51  19800000.00 -122.094000  47.60000
52     35500.00   -5.448100  57.27850
53    100500.00   -5.445000  57.59120
54     96400.00   -5.392200  57.51680
55     14400.00   -5.305400  57.25070
56     16400.00   -5.103700  57.17190
57    311000.00   -5.024400  57.71260
58     75500.00   -4.954900  57.49550
59     53600.00   -4.936500  57.45240
60    216100.00   -4.954400  57.68130
61     56000.00   -4.935600  57.80980
62    144600.00   -3.538200  56.88500
63     43000.00   -3.299100  54.48120
64  14918400.00  -89.672000  46.02900
65    618453.00  -89.700000  46.00800
66    820000.00   -4.031300  55.79300
67   4100000.00    3.630000  52.88000
68       566.00  -89.431000  46.00300
69     10478.00  -89.686000  46.04100
70   8900000.00   -2.889000  54.57610
71   2350000.00 -122.335100  47.63900
72  54000000.00  177.088000 -38.76800
73  88000000.00 -122.257000  47.61800
74     48657.67  -89.502830  46.23562
75   6700000.00   -2.930000  54.35000
76   1300000.00  -89.417800  43.05370
77    164000.00  -85.383000  42.39800
```

and I have generated a world map of these points with:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
mdat <- map_data('world')

str(mdat)
ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(dat=mdat, aes(long, lat, group=group), fill="grey50") +
  geom_point(data=dd, 
             aes(x = Lon, y = Lat, size=`area`), col="red")
```

resulting in:

[image]

From here, however, I can see 6 distinct regions:
1. Washington 2. Great Lakes Region 3. UK. 4. New Zealand 5. Rest of Europe. 6. Israel

What is the best way of splitting this map up into 6 panels to demonstrate the regions better. Note that the red circles represent different sizes of a particular variable and I would like the size to be carried between the panels i.e. not a separate legend for each panel.

I was eventually hoping of producing something like

[image]

although each panel should represent different regions of the world, as specified above.

Comment: This sounds a little bit like facetting with free scales but I have no idea if you can do that with maps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, because of the maps the free scales on `ggplot` don't work.  I don't know of any way to manually specify scales for each facet, so there are three possible solutions:

1. Only ask `ggplot` to plot the areas you're interested in.  This is laborious, but works (see solution here)
2. Do multiple `ggplot` plots looping by region and specifying scales manually, and then re-assemble (either with `grid` or manually)
3. Most elegant would be to get the map data, and then "cookie cutter it" to leave just the regions you want, with the polygons closed off appropriately.

While 3. would be better, the algorithm for the cookie cuttering would probably take me longer than the hackish #1 solution above, so here is #1:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
df <- df[complete.cases(df),]
df$dist.london <- sqrt((df$Lat - 51.5) ^ 2 + (df$Lon - 0.1275) ^ 2)
df$rg <- cut(df$dist.london, c(0, 10, 35, 65, 100, 150, 300), include.lowest=T)
levels(df$rg) <- c("UK", "RoE", "Israel", "Midwest", "US West", "New Zealand")

RoE <- c("France", "Germany", "Denmark", "Spain", "Italy", "Belgium", "Netherlands")
West <- tolower(c("Washington", "Oregon", "California", "Nevada", "Idaho"))
Lakes <- tolower(c("Michigan", "Illinois", "Wisconsin", "Indiana", "Ohio", "New York"))
mdat <- rbind(
  map_data('world', c("UK", RoE, "Israel", "New Zealand")),
  map_data("state", c(West, Lakes))
)
reg.map <- rbind(
  cbind(RoE, "RoE"),
  cbind(West, "US West"),
  cbind(Lakes, "Midwest"),
  cbind("UK", "UK"),
  cbind("Israel", "Israel"),
  cbind("New Zealand", "New Zealand")
)
mdat$rg <- factor(reg.map[match(mdat$region, reg.map[, 1]), 2], levels=levels(df$rg))
mdat <- subset(mdat, !(rg == "RoE" & (lat < 35 | long < -20)))
mdat <- subset(mdat, !(rg == "UK" & (lat < 50 | long < -20)))
mdat <- subset(mdat, !(rg == "New Zealand" & (lat > -20 | long < 100)))

ggplot(data=df) + 
  geom_polygon(dat=mdat, aes(long, lat, group=group), fill="grey50", color="grey10") +
  geom_point(aes(x = Lon, y = Lat, size=`area`), col="red") +
  facet_wrap(~ rg, scales="free")
```

[image]

I got lazy with the great lakes region and RoE, but you get the idea.